# Proving that a triangle is isosceles.

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a triangle $ABC$, let $D$ be a point on the segment $BC$ such that $AB + BD = AC + CD$. Suppose that the points $B,C$ and the centroids of triangles $ABD$ and $ACD$ lie on a circle. Prove that $AB = AC$.

I began this way: Denote the centroid of triangle $ABD$ by $G_1$ and the centroid of triangle $ACD$ by $G_2$. Then by using $Basic$ $Proportionality$ $Theorem$, I got that $BG_1G_2C$ is an isosceles trapezium. After that I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Try to prove that BD=CD

Comment: Yup, I tried that, too, @Moti. But I feel I am missing something which I could gather from the given information (or by any other manipulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, in the standard notation $$c+BD=b+a-BD,$$ which gives
$$BD=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$$ and $$CD=\frac{a+c-b}{2}.$$

Thus, $$CG_2=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{2b^2+2\left(\frac{a+c-b}{2}\right)^2-AD^2}$$ and
$$BG_1=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{2c^2+2\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)^2-AD^2},$$ which gives
$$2b^2+2\left(\frac{a+c-b}{2}\right)^2-AD^2=2c^2+2\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)^2-AD^2$$ or
$$(b-c)(b+c-a)=0$$ or $$b=c.$$